# Session duration in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

Is there any way in R to compute duration for each session when data is like these :

```
actionId;SessionId;Date
1;1;"2018-02-02 08:10:00"
2;1;"2018-02-02 08:30:00"
3;1;"2018-02-02 09:01:00"
4;2;"2018-03-01 09:01:00"
5;2;"2018-05-10 09:01:00"
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
df = read.table(text='actionId;SessionId;Date
1;1;"2018-02-02 08:10:00"
                2;1;"2018-02-02 08:30:00"
                3;1;"2018-02-02 09:01:00"
                4;2;"2018-03-01 09:01:00"
                5;2;"2018-05-10 09:01:00"',sep=';',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(df$Date)) %>%
  group_by(SessionId) %>%
  summarize(duration = max(Date)-min(Date))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  SessionId duration        
      <int> <time>          
1         1 51              
2         2 69.9583333333333
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's it. Thanks you very much

Comment: But before that, we should convert the date to timestamp 
The unit of duration wasn't the same (for sessionId = 1 in secs and in the other one in day) 

It would be helpful :

Answer (score 0):

But before that, we should convert the date to timestamp 
The unit of duration wasn't the same (for sessionId = 1 in secs and in the other one in day)

It would be helpful :

```
df = read.table(text='actionId;SessionId;Date
1;1;"2018-02-02 08:10:00"
                2;1;"2018-02-02 08:30:00"
                3;1;"2018-02-02 09:01:00"
                4;2;"2018-03-01 09:01:00"
                5;2;"2018-05-10 09:01:00"',sep=';',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

df$Date <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(df$Date))              


library(dplyr)


dur <- df %>% mutate(Date = df$Date) %>%
    group_by(SessionId) %>%
    summarize(duration = max(Date)-min(Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

But before that, we should convert the date to timestamp 
The unit of duration wasn't the same (for sessionId = 1 in secs and in the other one in day)

It would be helpful :

```
 dur <- df %>% mutate(Date = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Date))) %>%
        group_by(SessionId) %>%
        summarize(duration = max(Date)-min(Date))
```